# Group by date sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am trying to group this by the date as well. How can I do that? I want one group to be 0-30 another to be 31-60 and the last to be 60+. I am making a graph with SSRS and need the horizontal axis to be 0-31, 31-60 and 60+. I tried adding "THEN P_NUMBER END) as Active_age" to the end of the datediff but that doesn't work.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Assignment, Severity
FROM dashboard.dbo.SmTickets
WHERE Assignment IN('Crosby')
AND Severity IN(4)
AND datediff(day,Open_Time,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30 
group by Assignment, Severity
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) Assignment, Severity
FROM dashboard.dbo.SmTickets
WHERE Assignment IN('Crosby')
AND Severity IN(5)
AND datediff(day,Open_Time,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30 THEN P_NUMBER END) as Active_age
group by Assignment, Severity 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) Assignment, Severity
FROM dashboard.dbo.SmTickets
WHERE Assignment IN('Crosby')
AND Severity IN(4)
AND datediff(day,Open_Time,GETDATE()) between 30.01 and 60
group by Assignment, Severity 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) Assignment, Severity
FROM dashboard.dbo.SmTickets
WHERE Assignment IN('Crosby')
AND Severity IN(5)
AND datediff(day,Open_Time,GETDATE()) between 30.01 and 60
group by Assignment, Severity 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) Assignment, Severity
FROM dashboard.dbo.SmTickets
WHERE Assignment IN('Crosby')
AND Severity IN(4)
AND datediff(day,Open_Time,GETDATE()) > 60
group by Assignment, Severity 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) Assignment, Severity
FROM dashboard.dbo.SmTickets
WHERE Assignment IN('Crosby')
AND Severity IN(5)
AND datediff(day,Open_Time,GETDATE()) > 60
group by Assignment, Severity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
Select Assignment,Severity,[Days],Sum(NumberOfThingies) From
(
select Assignment,Severity,1 as NumberOfThingies, 
case when datediff(day,Open_Time,GETDATE) <= 30 Then '0 - 30'
case when datediff(day,Open_Time,GETDATE) <= 60 then '30 - 60'
else 'More than 60'
end as [Days]
FROM dashboard.dbo.SmTickets
Where Assignment in('Crosby') and Severity In (4,5)
) dummyname
Group By Assignment,Severity,[Days]
```

Comment: Try wrapping Days in square brackets.